# Customize Android Magnifier Widget View

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using [Magnifier Widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Magnifier) and I want to change its layout.


It's default like above

[image: default view]


I would like to put some image like above ober the magnifier view to show the center point to users.

[image]

Is that possible?

Or is there any way to get the current shown by the magnifier? If I can get the magnifier's momentary image by drawable. I can put the another imageview.

Comment: At API level 29, you can use `Magnifier.Builder`'s [`setOverlay(Drawable)` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Magnifier.Builder#setOverlay(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)). I'm not sure if we can do the equivalent on 28, which was before the `Builder` was introduced.

Comment: Nope, we can't, 'cause the overlay also wasn't added until 29. Unfortunately, that probably means that you just can't do it on Pie, 'cause that's the version that started locking down on reflection and such.

Comment: @MikeM.  This works when builder design is used. Thanks a lot.